# Get delimeters with split string output

Tags: c#, string, split

I want to split a string at multiple delimeters and would want to get the delimeters in the output. For example, if the input string is `Hello World` and my delimeters are `'l','o'`, the output array of strings should be `"He", "l", "l", "o", " W","o","r","l","d"`.Is there a built in function for that? `String.Split` does not have such an option. I remember, `StringTokenizer` in java had this option. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regexp.Split for it.
For example:

```
  Dim input As String = "Hello World"    
  Dim pattern As String = "(l)|(o)" 
  For Each result As String In Regex.Split(input, pattern) 
     Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", result)
  Next
```

For more information about Regex.Split, please visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

These extension methods works:

```
public static class SplitEx
{
    public static string[] SplitInline(this string text, char delimeter)
    {
        var results = text.Split(delimeter);
        return
            results
                .Take(1)
                .Concat(
                    results
                        .Skip(1)
                        .SelectMany(x => new []
                        {
                            Convert.ToString(delimeter),
                            x,
                        }))
                .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                .ToArray();
    }

    public static string[] SplitInline(this string text, string delimeters)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(delimeters))
        {
            return new [] { text };
        }
        else
        {
            var head = delimeters[0];
            var tail = new string(delimeters.Skip(1).ToArray());
            return
                text
                    .SplitInline(head)
                    .SelectMany(x => x.SplitInline(tail))
                    .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
var text = "Hello World";

var result = text.SplitInline("lo");
```

I get the following result:

[image: result]